# Conditional formatting in Excel 2013 based on inequality between two cells

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

This is part of a problem for college for which I can't find a solution.

> Use conditional formatting to format, in blue and bold, the value in column 8 for which the value in column 5 is greater than the value in column 2.

I only need the basics to get started on this step. I can develop from there.

Example: before formatting

[image: before]

and after formatting

[image: after]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot do your homework for you, but we can give you pointers.

The Conditional Formatting command is on the Home ribbon.

If you want to format the current cell based on values in other cells, you will need a formula to determine which cells to format.

Such a formula needs to return either TRUE or FALSE. This formula returns a number (if the cells contain numbers): `=$A$1+$A$2` -- This formula returns either TRUE or FALSE: `=$A$1>$A$2`, depending on which number is greater.

When you build a formula for conditional formatting, you can either type a cell reference or click a cell.

Conditional formatting can be copied to other areas of the spreadsheet, for example from one row down to other rows.

When a formula applies to more than one row of data, you may want to use references that are relative to the current row, so you don't want any $ signs before the row number.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. After some research, adding up with your hint and various attempts at getting the right formula I finally got it.